# Block directory access with .htaccess rules does not work

Tags: htaccess

I am trying to block access to a specific folder and all of its content. I use methods suggested on the Internet, but they do not work.

This method does nothing:

```
RewriteRule ^folder_name/?$ - [F,L]
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

And this one brings internal server error:

```
<Directory "/folder_name/">
deny from all
</Directory>
```

What is wrong here?

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

#rewrite rules for base URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)[/]*$ $1\.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Aparently, you are not supposed to use Directory directive in htaccess, but interesting why rewrite rule does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method that works:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/folder_name/.*$
```

Comment: But note that the existing mod_rewrite directives are still processed before this mod_alias directive is processed, regardless of the order of the directives, so any redirects will still happen.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^folder_name/?$ - [F,L]
> ```

This blocks access to the folder only; not its contents (because of the trailing end-of-string anchor). And since you have existing mod_rewrite directives, it will need to go near the top, *before* the existing directives.

Generally, you should have blocking directives first.

```
RewriteRule ^folder_name - [F]

: remaining directives follow
```

Alternatively, you create another `.htaccess` file inside the directory you want to block, with a single directive:

```
Require all denied
```

Comment: This is a better answer.